# How to define schema for mongoDB Collections in Yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii2, php-mongodb

I am using the `mongoDB` with `PHP` and want to define the schema.

I know that `mongoDB` is schemaless, but in `NodeJS` we have a plugin `mongoose` by which we can define the schema for `mongoDB`.

So how can I define the schema for `mongoDB collection` in `Yii2` like `mongoose`.

Answer (score 1):

Yii2's standard [MongoDB extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html) provides Yii2 [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) support with declarative schema and validation similar to Mongoose. The Yii2 extension also includes support for generating starter classes (models, controllers, etc) using the [`gii` generator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html).

For more information and examples see:

- Yii2 docs: [MongoDB Extension for Yii 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html)
- Yii2 wiki: [MongoDB embedded documents mapping for ActiveRecord in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/632/mongodb-s-embedded-documents-mapping-for-activerecord-in-yii2/)

Comment: Okay but in mongoose we can define the reference and can define that a field can be an array of defined type and the validation of the sub field level can also we defined. Can we do that in yii? If yes could you please elaborate with example?